# $(selector).val() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an option list in my view that gets its options set via ajax in `$(document).ready()` After this ajax call, I want to set the value of this field to a using `.val()`

My ajax call is made via the following function:

```
 function getOrganisations(date, id, blank) {
    $.get(myBaseUrl + "/placements/getTempsOrgsForTimesheets/" + blank + "?date=" + date + "&id=" + id,
        function (data, status) {
            $(".organisation").html(data);
        });
}
```

This function works fine and populates the list correctly

If, after this I try to set the value of this list, it doesn't work using

```
$("#org_" + rel).val($("#org_" + rel).attr("aVal"));
```

If I type this into the console in my browser it works fine and updates the field.

Any Ideas?

```
<div class="input select"><select name="timeData[organisation_id][thu]" class="organisation table-data table-row-3" aval="38" rel="3" id="org_3"><option value="0"> </option><option value="38">DFS Cork</option></select></div>
```

I've added

```
 console.log(document.getElementById("org_" + rel));
```

just before I try and set the value and got the following

```
<select name="timeData[organisation_id][thu]" class="organisation table-data table-row-3" aval="38" rel="3" id="org_3"><option value="0"> </option><option value="38">DFS Cork</option></select>
```

Comment: If you don't see anything in the error console, its likely the element you are trying to wrap is not exists.

try to debug by using 
`console.log(document.getElementById("org_" + rel));`

ie: 
`console.log(document.getElementById("org_" + rel));
$("#org_" + rel).val($("#org_" + rel).attr("aVal"));`

and show me what you see then.

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine this is an asynchronous issue.

It works in your browser console because by then the AJAX call would have completed.

Ensure you're adding the line in the call back function.

```
function (data, status) {
   $('#place_' + rel).html(data);
   $("#org_" + rel).val($("#org_" + rel).attr("aVal"));   
});
```

---

If you don't want to add the logic directly into your `getOrganisations` function you could include a `callback` parameter instead:

```
 function getOrganisations(date, id, blank, callback) {
    $.get(myBaseUrl + "/placements/getTempsOrgsForTimesheets/" + blank + "?date=" + date + "&id=" + id,
        function (data, status) {
            $(".organisation").html(data);
            if (typeof callback === 'function'){
               callback();
            }
        });
}
```

Then use it like:

```
getOrganisations('date_value', 'id_value', 'blank_value', function(){
   $("#org_" + rel).val($("#org_" + rel).attr("aVal"));  
});
```

Comment: You people are so fast

Comment: The Ajax request always runs on the page, but this update of setting the value is conditional so I don't want it in place on the ajax callback. Can I have it wait until all ajax requests are complete?

Comment: @mcgowan.b See my update. You can pass an optional callback function into your `getOrganisations` method. This would be better practice anyway as it ensures seperation of concerns.